# How do I fade 2 images with jQuery on mouseenter and mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, fadeout

I have a custom button (code below). I want it to:

- rotate quickly 360 on `mouseenter` (currently working fine)
- fade quickly to a darker image on `mouseenter` (also currently working fine)
- NOT un-rotate on `mouseleave` (currently working fine)

I can't yet figure out how to:

- fade back to the original image on `mouseleave` (**not working yet**)

I have tried so many variations of jQuery including `.hover`, `.fadeToggle`, `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` as well as `animate` but none have seemed to work for me.

Am I missing something really simple and obvious?

NOTE: I have just used the Apple logo for demonstration here. If I can get the 'fade back on mouseleave' working I can just transfer it to my real life situation.

```js
  var thevalue = 1;
$("div.main").mouseenter(function() {

  thevalue = thevalue + 1;
  if (thevalue % 2 == 0) {
    $(this).addClass("myopacity");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("myopacity");
  }

  $(this).addClass("change").delay(500).queue(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("change").dequeue();
  });
  
});
```

```css
div.main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
div.main img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.change {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
.myopacity {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/apple-logo_318-40184.jpg">
  </div>

  <p id="dis"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8wv71d3f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Trying to manage two transitions on the exact same element was making it too complicated.

I ended up having to add one class to the `img` element and another to the `div` element.  The `img` element now manages the rotation and the `div` element manages the fade through simple CSS `:hover` transitions.

This makes the jQuery much more simple.

See updated code below:

```js
$("div.main").mouseenter(function() {
  
  $(".image").addClass("change").delay(500).queue(function() {
    $(".image").removeClass("change").dequeue();
  });
  
});
// jQuery now much more simple. No need for variables or the if/else statement
```

```css
div.main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
/* This will take care of the fade transition on :hover */

div.main img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.change {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
/* .myopacity {
  opacity: 0.6;
} */
/* The .myopacity class is no longer necessary as it's taken care of through the div.main:hover class below */

div.main:hover, div.main:active, div.main:focus {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/apple-logo_318-40184.jpg" class="image">
  </div>

  <p id="dis"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Kind of cheated with not using jQuery for the fade transition (as originally hoped for) but this works equally as well!

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want. hope this will help to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">

div.main{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 
}

div.main img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.change{
 -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition-duration: 5s;
}


</style>


<body>

<div class="main">
<img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/apple-logo_318-40184.jpg">
</div>

<p id="dis"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

var thevalue = 1;
$("div.main").mouseenter(function(){
 $(this).addClass("change").fadeTo('fast',0.7).delay(5000).queue(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("change").fadeTo('slow',1.0).dequeue();
 });
 
});



</script>




</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Almost. I want the opacity to **fade** back to normal (opacity: 1). @AnuradhS

Comment: in here, when you `mouse enter` the `opacity :0.7`, then after the rotation `opacity:1.0`. so?

Comment: The opacity needs to be **gradual**. The above is changing to `opacity:1.0` **instantly**. I can't be instant, it must be gradual. @AnuradhS

Comment: updated the answer, check it now. change the `slow` to any value `ex:1000`(fade in time), as your need.

Comment: Very close. It must fade back to normal on `mouseleave`. The above fades back while the mouse is still on the element @AnuradhS

Comment: you want to fade back in any time `mouseleave`, while rotating also is it okay.

Comment: Yes, the image must fade back on `mouseleave`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what you are after... I think this is close. Rotates 360° and opacity dims to 60%, then rotates back to 0° and full opacity.

No clue why you even needed the opacity class or the associated jQuery for it.

```js
$("div.main").hover( 
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('change').addClass('myopacity');
  },
  function() {
     $(this).removeClass('myopacity')
  });
```

```css
body { padding: 40px; }

div.main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  background: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/apple-logo_318-40184.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
div.main img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main.change {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: all .5s;
  background: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/windows-8-logo_318-40228.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.change.myopacity { 
  opacity: .6; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">
  </div>

  <p id="dis"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want the images in the actual HTML, then you can use the jQuery hover function to alter the image sources.

Comment: I need the associated jQuery because I don't want it to un-rotate on `mouseleave`.

Comment: @KingDesigns Oh, okay.. I thought you *did* want it to rotate back on mouse leave. Check the updated snippet... won't rotate back now, but the opacity will transition back to 100%..... and still don't need that extra jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified the exact situation. It's a 'back to top' that I'm building. It must rotate360 **each** time the mouse enters. I have a slightly darker image that it fades to at the same time that must fade **back** to the original image on mouseleave (without un-rotating the entire div). Thus the complication. @Scott

Comment: Well I give up :) Each comment provides more information. Not going to continually edit to try and chase what you *really* want. Good luck, though. Hope you sort it all out.